# Why SOQL if firing Twice in Controller

Tags: custom-controller

```
public List<test_revenue__x> getRevenudetails() {
    List<test_revenue__x> revenuelistquery=[select master_customer_nbr__c,master_customer_name__c,customer_po_nbr__c,order_nbr__c,quick_look_id__c,invoice_quater__c,invoice_month__c from test_revenue__x where quick_look_id__c IN:qlkid];

    for(test_revenue__x revn:revenuelistquery){
        system.debug('Testrevenur' +revn);
        if(selectedreports =='Revenue YTD'){
            revenuelist.add(revn);
        }

    }
    return revenuelist;
}
```

It is retuning duplicate records to vf page due SOQL is firing twice.Can i know the reason for the cause?

`List<current_year_revenue_summary__x> revenuelistquery=[select master_customer_nbr__c,master_customer_name__c,customer_po_nbr__c,order_nbr__c,quick‌​_look_id__c,invoice_quater__c,invoice_month__c from current_year_revenue_summary__x where quick_look_id__c IN:qlkid];` –

Comment: It is retuning duplicate records to vf page due SOQL is firing twice.Can i know the reason for the cause?      List<current_year_revenue_summary__x> revenuelistquery=[select master_customer_nbr__c,master_customer_name__c,customer_po_nbr__c,order_nbr__c,quick_look_id__c,invoice_quater__c,invoice_month__c from current_year_revenue_summary__x where quick_look_id__c IN:qlkid];

Comment: what is **qlkid and selectedreports** in your code?

Comment: qlkid is  text field in user object and selectedreports is selected List Value in vf page.

Comment: You are ReInitialize the **revenuelist** after or before the **SOQL** execution like
`revenuelist = new List<test_revenue__x>();`

Comment: Tq you so much!! It works fine now!!

Comment: Your welcome @user33763.  I'll post my answer and you select the answer. We'll close this question.

Comment: Please close this question. Please select the usable answer. @user33763

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may help to your scenario

```
public List<test_revenue__x> getRevenudetails() {

    revenuelist = new List<test_revenue__x>();  // Reinitialize the revenuelist List
    List<test_revenue__x> revenuelistquery=[select master_customer_nbr__c,master_customer_name__c,customer_po_nbr__c,order_nbr__c,quick_look_id__c,invoice_quater__c,invoice_month__c from test_revenue__x where quick_look_id__c IN:qlkid];

    for(test_revenue__x revn:revenuelistquery){
        system.debug('Testrevenur' +revn);
        if(selectedreports =='Revenue YTD'){
            revenuelist.add(revn);
        }

    }
    return revenuelist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, getters should be self-contained and the only decision to make is whether each invocation should return the same list or, if there is a possibility of the list changing between requests (such as AJAX refreshes across DML events.

**Always refetch list**

```
public List<Test_Revenue__x> getRevenudetails() {
   return this.selectedRevenueReports == 'Revenue YTD'
             ? [select id, ... from Test_Revenue__x where ...]
             : new List<Test_Revenue__x();    
}
```

**Fetch only once (invariant list)**

```
public List<Test_Revenue__x> Revenudetails {
   get {
        if (this.Revenudetails == null) 
            this.Revenudetails = this.selectedRevenueReports == 'Revenue YTD'
                                  ? [select id, ... from Test_Revenue__x where ...]
                                  : new List<Test_Revenue__x();
        return this.Revenudetails ;  // return cached value
      }
   set;
 }
```